# Will React Native work with ad SDK's?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactjs-native

I know this isn't a specific code question, but I have asked in a lot of places and haven't gotten a completely clear answer. I'm hoping SO can help me.

I'm about to start a moderately complicated React Native project for both iOS and Android.

I'm confident the whole app can be built just fine with RN or a mix of RN and native code.

The one thing I want to make 100% sure of before I start, is that there won't be any problems or hangups with any advertisement SDK (tremor media, bright roll, flurry, tap joy, etc, etc).

I'm ok with having to code them in pure native code, so long as there are no conflicts which RN might introduce which would make it flat out incompatible/impossible to have (probably intricate) ad SDK implementations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve been doing some digging on this myself. And here is what I've found so far.

**AdMob: Supported and verified**
I managed to make this work. In terms of dependency, AdMob requires FireBase. But FireBase does not support React Native out of box. I used a wrapper called React-Native-Firebase to make it work. https://rnfirebase.io/
https://firebase.google.com/
https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/react-native/react-native-admob/

**FB Ads: Supported**
I haven’t verified it myself. But it seems to be well documented. (And React Native being related to Facebook, I’d be surprised if it weren’t supported.) https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbads

**Flurry: NOT supported**
Flurry Analytics supports React Native but Flurry Ads do not. Below is message from their support team when I asked them about this.
"Thank you for contacting Flurry Technical Support. We offer a React Native wrapper, however it does not currently support ads, only analytics. You can read more about it here: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/react-native/ "

**MoPub: Not really**
I’ve found two React Native wrappers. One is old and no longer updated. (The authors seem to be actively monitoring the discussions and replying to queries. But they are no longer providing tech support.) And the other is very new and doesn’t seem to have enough documentation or evidence that it actually works.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mopub
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mopub-sdk

Answer (score 1):

I wrote admob wrapper for RN, If you want to admob please check this out: [melihmucuk@react-native-admob-sample](https://github.com/melihmucuk/react-native-admob-sample)

If you want to others, you should find wrapper or write yourself.